# RejectedExecutionException has occured in coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

the rejectedexecutionexception occurs on app but does not point out from which action/thread/class its coming from. I have used nothing to manually shutdown threads or anything. But this is coming from coroutines

```
 Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@eeb06f2 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@75be143[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 0]
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2086)
    java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:562)
    a.a.b.a.b.d.c.a (c.java:4)
    a.a.b.a.b.d.a.a (a.java:21)
    a.a.b.a.b.b.a (b.java:5)
    a.a.b.a.b.e.a.a (a.java:19)
    a.a.b.a.c.e.a$c.invokeSuspend (a.java:6)
    kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (BaseContinuationImpl.java:33)
    a.a.a.o0.run (o0.java:28)
    a.a.a.c2.a$a.run (a.java:590)
```

Comment: have you found the core of the problem? I have the same issue and have no idea what exactly could lead to this. Has a lot of logs in firebase, but they are completely different each crash.